# StreamWriter does not emit BOM for UTF-7

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding

Have a look at this very simple piece of code:

```
private static void WriteTestLine(string file, Encoding encoding)
{
    // 'Hello, world!' in russian
    const string testLine = "Здравствуй, мир!";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path: file, append: false, encoding: encoding))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(testLine);
    }

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path: file, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadLine());
    }
}

WriteTestLine("utf8", new UTF8Encoding(true));
WriteTestLine("utf7", new UTF7Encoding(true));
WriteTestLine("utf7woOptionals", new UTF7Encoding(false));
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Здравствуй, мир!
+BBcENARABDAEMgRBBEIEMgRDBDk-, +BDwEOARA-!
+BBcENARABDAEMgRBBEIEMgRDBDk-, +BDwEOARAACE-
```

As you can see, `StreamReader` was unable to detect UTF-7 encoding correctly. Indeed, if you open both UTF-7 files with a hex editor, in both cases the first four bytes will look like this:

```
2B 42 42 63
```

But [Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that UTF-7 should have a BOM that looks like one of the following:

```
2B 2F 76 38
2B 2F 76 39
2B 2F 76 2B
2B 2F 76 2F
2B 2F 76 38 2D
```

So I guess that .NET's `StreamWriter` is unable to work correctly with UTF-7. That seems odd. Do i miss something? How can I force `StreamWriter` to emit BOM in UTF-7 files?

P.S. By the way:

```
Encoding.UTF7.GetPreamble();
```

produces an empty array

Comment: Well, you already know why, without an override for GetPreamble() there cannot be any BOM detection.  You can override it if you really want to and fix that problem.  Although you'd be stumped which one to pick :)  Don't use it.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there any reason why UTF-7 isn't implemented properly? Maybe UTF-7 is so rare that nobody uses it?

Comment: Right, nobody uses it.  The world has moved to 8 bit bytes.

Comment: `UTF8Encoding` has a constructor with a parameter "encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier", `UTF7Encoding` does not (no remarks about that on MSDN either). I don't think your statement ".NET's StreamWriter is unable to work correctly with UTF-7" is completely correct though, you can still have valid UTF-7 without a BOM.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis string encoded in UTF-7 is a base64 string, therefore it consists of ASCII characters only. There is no way to distinguish between ASCII and UTF-7 without BOM

Comment: @RX_DID_RX Checking the specific patterns can _exclude_ UTF-7 as possibility though. As for actually _implementing_ UTF-7 with BOM, though, that seems really tricky, if the first two bits of the first encoded character are inside the preamble. It means the whole encoding doesn't match the assumptions of a simple fixed preamble made by the Encoding superclass.